# Как работать с R.java при модификации

Tags: android, r.java-file

Добавляю в чужое приложение функционала, столкнулся с проблемой в добавлении новых id. С лэйаутами все легко и просто, я дополняю R$id.smali статическими данными следуя порядку 16-ричной системы. Например, последний стоит `0x7f03008d`, значит дополнять нужно свой `0x7f03008e` и т.д. Но это с layout-ами. А как быть с id? Вот такой вот список (последние 5)

```
.field public static final welcome_sync_opt3:I = 0x7f0801cc

.field public static final writebar_attach:I = 0x7f0801e0

.field public static final writebar_edit:I = 0x7f0801de

.field public static final writebar_line:I = 0x7f0801e1

.field public static final writebar_send:I = 0x7f0801df
```

Comment: И смысл ставить минус? За что?

Comment: R вообще не трогайте! там все это дело автоматизировано

Comment: да минусуют за то, что вы, по всей видимости, пытаетесь внести "дополнительный" функционал не в свое приложение.